# ReactJS custom controls can't access parameters

Tags: reactjs

OK, so this is driving me bonkers and I'm sure I'm missing something really simple.

I'm trying to pass data to a custom control. This arrives as an object. I can log the object to the console, but when I try to log the object's properties, I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined". If I pass a string, then I can access this without any problems. The (very truncated) examples below show the the results with object being successfully logged to the console, and failure when I try to access the properties.

Invoking code:

```
<CustomControl initialValue={countries[0]} />
```

Invoked code which works:

```
function CustomControl({initialValue}) {
  console.log(initialValue);
}
```

and the console log

`{key: 520728, text: 'UK'}`

Invoked code which fails:

```
function CustomControl({initialValue}) {
  console.log(initialValue.text);
}
```

and the console log

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')`

All hints and tips will be very gratefully received!

Comment: Browsers consoles often perform lazy-evaluation on logged objects, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(initialValue))` to make sure that the object actually exists at the point you are logging it.

Comment: I imagine this boils down to: "You are rendering `CustomControl` before there are any array elements in `countries`, so `countries[0]` is `undefined`"

Comment: I think you're correct. The array is populated in the **useEffect** method of the creating component: I suspect there's a timing issue. Thank you, @DBS

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `initialValue` is undefined initially. You should be able to see `undefined` output before the actual log.
If that is the case, use `?` operator to prevent accessing the unavailable properties as below.

```
function CustomControl({initialValue}) {
  console.log(initialValue?.text);
}
```